# What are the options for expanding the available storage on a VPS?

Tags: linux, vps, storage, cloud-storage

I have several virtual servers hosted at Linode, and I'm looking for a way to expand the available storage capacity. On some of those servers I'd need to have between 0.5 and 2 TB of space.

Basically these are my requirements:

- Storage should be easily mountable on a Linux server (for example through sshfs), without requiring proprietary software or GUI tools.
- I don't need any of the extra features that most cloud storage providers offer (such as backups, synchronization, encryption, CDN, etc). I just need lots of storage space.
- Pricing should be reasonable (hopefully < $ 0.10/GB/month)

I've been doing a lot of research on this, but unfortunately I haven't found a good solution yet.

Some colleagues have suggested getting a dedicated server with plenty of storage on an affordable price range (it seems like a good advice, but I was wondering if there are any better options).

So what I'd like to ask you is what kind of service / technology would you recommend for a case like this.

Please note that even if that would be truly useful, I'm not asking for a specific service recommedation (which is not allowed according to the FAQ). I'm just asking for some help with my research. I appreciate your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I'd second the suggestion of your colleagues — a server by hetzner.de would by far be the easiest and most affordable solution.  If you are in NA, and need better latency to US/Canada and Asia, then you can also try the new ovh.ca datacentre in Quebec.

Comment: Yeap.  And ping.ovh.ca is under 10ms away from NYC, so, their current offerings (2-core Sandy Bridge i3, 8GB RAM, 2x 1TB, 5TB@100Mbps @ 39,00$/mo) are actually quite a deal, indeed. :)

Comment: Hetzner and OVH are the last two places I would ever lease servers from, and only if they were the only options. Other than that, this is good advice.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, Hetzner and OVH are often the only options.  Who else offers affordable dedicated servers?

Comment: Oh, just a few thousand other companies...

Comment: @MichaelHampton, please name one that offers Sandy Bridge i3, 8GB RAM, 2x 1TB storage and 5TB@100Mbps traffic for 39 USD/month.  Or same with 16GB RAM for 49 USD/month.  With a 1-month contract, no setup fees.  Closest reasonable and comparable alternative would require a 36-month contract, a huge setup fee, and will still be more expensive than this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton : I can see that your reputation precedes you, and it is clear that you have a great deal of expertise in this area. For this particular project I don't need high levels of reliability or availability (which perhaps I should've made more clear in my question). Anyway I understand your concerns with regard to some providers. Would you care to share which ones would you trust? Thanks!

Comment: @alemartini, technically, you're supposed to have ECC RAM for any computer to be reliable; the saying is that without ECC RAM, a wrong bit flip in the kernel memory that deals with the filesystem, might theoretically ruin your whole filesystem, together with all the RAIDs, and could require professional repair (such situation is somewhat hypothetical, and there generally aren't any actual reports, but it is still something that many people don't advise playing with, e.g. http://cr.yp.to/hardware/ecc.html)

Comment: and, unfortunately, many hetzner.de and almost all ovh.ca deals don't have any ECC support whatsoever; with OVH, even their introductory Xeon models don't have ECC support (I've specifically asked OVH.ca whether SP2 and SP3 have ECC; they said they don't).  With hetzner.de, their ECC starts at only 69 EUR, but requires a setup fee of 69 EUR (which is still a very good deal, but not a complete bargain as many of their other offers).  BTW, if you're outside of EU, one hetzner.de EUR equals roughly one USD, since they include a 19% VAT in their prices, which they won't charge outside of EU.